# Binomial distribution - $n$ for an "at least" Probability

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, sample-size

**Question**: In a binomial distribution for $p=0.48, q=1-p=0.52$, find the population size $n_1$ so that  $P(X>=3)=0.95$.

**My solution :**

$P(X\geq3)=0.95$

can be rewritten as

$$P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=.05 \hspace{3cm} (1)$$

but I am unable to solve the above equation for $n_1$.

### Is there any way to solve the equation (1) or is there any alternate solution?

**Attempted solution is**

$\binom{n}{0}$ $q^n$ +  $\binom{n}{1}$ $p^1$$q^(n-1)$+$\binom{n}{2}$ $p^2$$q^(n-2)$=.05

$q^n$ + n(p/q)$q^2$ + (n(n-1)/2)$(p/q)^2$$q^n$=.05

$q^n$(1+np/q+(n(n-1)/2)$(p/q)^2$)=.05

after this i am not able to solve it further.

Comment: **1**. The question should ask for sample size not population size.$\:$ **2**. What's $P(X=k)$ in a $\text{binomial}(n_1,p)$?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Hi Glen_b, can you look into the shown **attempted** solution and suggest your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a formula for each of the three terms $P(X=0)$, $P(X=1)$, and $P(X=2)$ in terms of $n_1$ and $p$.

Putting in the known values, you get an equation in $n_1$ that is solvable (trial and error suffices, but you can be a bit more sophisticated about it if you are able to).

You can't solve it exactly, but you can find the smallest $n_1$ that will make the probability at least $0.95$.

Comment: Thanks Glen_b, understood it can't be solved for exact n1, i tried to solve for smallest n1 but did not get any success, please suggest your solution if you have any or if you have any other reference(s), please point out me so that i can study it to solve.

Comment: 1. Please respond to my comments under your question; you don't appear to have done what was requested. 2. Please show the working for your attempted solution (in an edit to your question)

Comment: Hi Glen_b, can you look into the shown **attempted** solution in question and suggest your answer.

Comment: What does my second paragraph already suggest?